# Ajax Control Toolkit Compile error ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I added AjaxControlToolkit version 7.1213 from nuget, and I have vs 2012 with .net 4.5
I try to use calenderextender in my website like this

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="birthtxt" runat="server" Style="width: 95%;" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

when trying to debug the project I got the following errors:

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.


Error   2   The type 'System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

and this is assemblies my `Web.config`

```
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

and this is `controls` in `web.config`

```
   <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

and the target frame work is 3.5
any idea???

Comment: Have you added the ajax controls dll to your bin folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. the problem is solved by adding to compliation tag in `web.config` the attribute targetframework like this

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't added the AjaxControlToolkit assembly to the Assemblies section. Could you try adding it in and then retesting?

EDIT: To get the PublicKeyToken, open Visual Studio Command Prompt, cd to the directory where your DLL is located and then issue below command:

```
sn -Tp AjaxControlToolkit.dll
```

Comment: how to get public key token??

Comment: I tried that and got this                                         
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.17929
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Failed to convert key to token -- Invalid assembly public key.

Comment: Did you use Tp with capital T? The flag is case-sensitive, so if you use lower case t you will get this issue.

Comment: I did all things you said and got this when retesting               The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly during runtime causing a failure: HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a. The dependencies are: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089; System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

Answer (score 1):

If am not wrong, this may be your issue take away below line from your web.config file

```
<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
```

and put that in top of your source page, and don't forget to put your tagprefix in last which mean after namespace declaration.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

and change like this in source page, because no connection between ajaxtoolkit and textbox.For that you have to use 'TargetControlID'

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="birthtxt">
    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

**UPDATE**

change your webconfig file as,

```
<pages>
<controls>

<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions,Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
        tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
</controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: Let me know the result.@FerasSalim

Comment: Put TargetControlID in ajaxtoolkit calendar extender instead of toolkitscript manager.